# Is it possible to use more reducer in app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it possible to use more reducer in app, I have created several reducer files and I want to share in provider. Is it possible? I tried not many things but without success, like for example: combineReducers.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers} from "redux";
//import reducer from "../src/reducer/TestReducer";
import reducerAuthentification from "../src/reducer/ReducerAuthentification"
import TestReducer from "../src/reducer/TestReducer"
import './assets/style/app/App.css';
import './assets/style/app/App.scss';
import React from 'react';

import Accueil from './view/accueil/Accueil';
import Feuillete from './view/patisserie/Feuilletes';
import Footer from './view/footer/Footer';
import Reservation from './view/reservation/Reservation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Compte from './view/client/compte/Compte';
const store = createStore(reducerAuthentification);
const store1 = createStore(TestReducer)
// const appReducers = createStore({
//   reducerAuthentification: "",
//   TestReducer: ""
// })

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={{store}}>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          {/* <Navbar/> */}
          <header className="App-header">
            <Navigation/>
          </header>
          <Routes>
            <Route path={"/"} element={<Accueil />}/>
            <Route path={"/les-patisseries/les-feuilletes"} element={<Feuillete />}/>
            <Route path={"/reservation"} element={<Reservation />}/>
            <Route path={"/compte"} element={<Compte />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to combine all reducer in separate file.
For example:

rootReducer.js:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer1: reducerOne,
    reducer2: reducerTwo,
})

export default rootReducer
```

store.js:

```
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

Redux `createStore` is depreceated method, it works but you should use `configureStore` for creating store.
See: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can use combineReducers as shown in their documentation.

https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers